# What to call pure JavaScript standalone (web)apps which have no server side?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-applications, terminology, client-side

I've been writing a few tools as standalone webapps that have no server side code and it strikes me that I'm not sure what people call such things.

I like them because they can be distributed as a single file that anybody with a web browser can run. Typically all the funky stuff is done by calling AJAX web APIs like those provided by Stack Exchange, MediaWiki, Google, etc.

The following terms all seem plausible but might also cover other things or not tell the whole story:

- client-only
- pure JavaScript
- standalone webapp
- web script
- web tool
- browser app

**Is one of these terms or something else in common use for such apps / tools?**

Here's links to some of my little tools on GitHub: [travel-se-airport-tags.html](https://gist.github.com/1513820), [travel-se-1-or-2-answers.html](https://gist.github.com/1561046), [travel-se-stats.html](https://gist.github.com/1608753)

There are some much more app-ish examples [in the 10k Challenge...](http://10k.aneventapart.com/faqs)

Comment: I don't mind if it lives here or on Programmers but it seems surprising that programming terminology questions would be off topic here.

Comment: For anyone interested, I did go on to ask this question on programmers: **[What to call pure JavaScript standalone (web)apps for which I've not written any server side code?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/130481/what-to-call-pure-javascript-standalone-webapps-for-which-ive-not-written-any)**

Comment: I'd like to reopen this old question as it seems there is now a widely used term for this kind of app, and it even has an abbreviation and its own tag here on Stack Overflow. **Single Page Application (SPA)**. [tag:single-page-application] - perhaps it does not meet my criteria point by point but it's certainly close enough that I now know what to call these when I make them, and how to tag future questions about them.

Answer (score 1):

In the fantastic [10K Challenge](http://10k.aneventapart.com/faqs), they are generally referred to as:

- Client-side apps

or

- Purely-client apps

But I think your first 3 titles are pretty self-explanatory too.